# Scripting color palette to align with corresponding classes from supervised classification in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, color, land-classification

When I display my classification map, the colors don't line up with the variable that I want them to. For example, my `forest` category is represented as red (instead of my goal color-green), or my `water` category shows up as gray (instead of 'blue').

How do I order my color palette such that it corresponds with the classes appropriately?

This is my script so far in Google Earth Engine:

```
//Create a classification map. Classify the input imagery
var classified = composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

//Define the palette for the land use classification

var palette = [
  '0000FF', // water (0)  -- blue
  'FFFF00', // cultivated (1)  -- yellow
  'DCDCDC', //  Settlement (2) -- gray
  'F0E68C', // Grasslands (3)--khaki
  '228B22', // forest  (4)-- forest green
  '000000', //clouds (5)-- black
  '808000', //intact veg (6)-- olive
  'FFA500', //impacted_veg (7)-- orange
  'DC143C', //mines (8)-- crimson
];

// Display the classification result and the input image.
Map.centerObject(K2C_aoi);
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 2, palette: palette}, 'Land Use Classification');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earth Engine's visualization does not have a special case for integer or discrete values; the palette colors will be applied across the numerical range specified in the visualization parameters, with linear interpolation in between.

So, change `max` from 2 to `palette.length - 1` (which will be the number of your last class, 8 in this case) to ensure the integer values in the image will line up with the palette entries.

```
Map.addLayer(classified, {
  min: 0,
  max: palette.length - 1,
  palette: palette
}, 'Land Use Classification');
```